# Как решить проблему с JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.01.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.202-ea
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно из этого предупреждения? Чем этот варнинг мешает? Скорее всего в fxml файле указана эта версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что это не проблема, а предупреждение. Я полагаю, что вы создавали fxml-форму в каком-то графическом приложении, например, SceneBuilder. По каким-то причинам это приложение проставило вашим формам такую вот версию, которая выше версии установленной джавы.

Вероятность того, что вы заюзали хоть какие-то фичи из новой версии (они там есть вообще?) JavaFX, которых нет в 8-й джаве, стремится к нулю. Просто не смотрите на ворнинги и всё.